# Database Schema knowledge boundaries

Tags: mysql, database, oop, design-patterns

I'm struggling to figure out where to put the knowledge about the database.

For example:

Lets say we have a database with operators of different enterprise and they operate in different states and different kinds of equipment. A operator can work in several states and for several companies for different kinds of equipment.

So to model that my db model is like:

```
Operator table (dni, id)
Company table (name, id)
Equipment table (name, id)
States table (name, id)
```

and the relation tables

```
OpComEq (idOp, idComp, idEq)
OpComSt (idOp, idComp, idSt)
```

So if we want to retrieve an operator, we have to cross query.
If a company tells us that a given operator no longer works with them, we have to delete all his links of this operator with this company had with states and with Equipments, and check if there is still any link with that operator (he might be working for another company etc) and if not, then delete him from the operator database.

The problem I encounter is not knowing where to encapsulate this knowledge, inside the database class or inside the Operator class or maybe is another class.

I know this is a concrete example but is an abstract problem I bet is already solved but i cant find the design pattern for this. Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but if I do then there is no solution. This problem is well known and called the [Object-Relational Mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) (or impedance).

Storing data in a Relational database imposes certain rules - e.g. that 3NF is met - which constrain how the data is organised. Writing code with OOP imposes different constraints. The two lead to mismatches in organisation of code and organisation of data. You just have to live with it.

(Incidentally, if you do come up with a general solution, please let us all know - life will be better!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm speaking as a database designer and DBA here, although I also do OOP. As a database designer I'll just point out in passing that you're missing a lot of tables, and that your problem has more to do with insufficient requirements than with the OR mismatch.

> So if we want to retrieve an operator, we have to cross query.

You can get the operator's id number from any table that contains it. If you also need the operator's name, then you need to join on the table of operators.

> If a company tells us that a given operator no longer works with them, we have to delete all his links of this operator with this company had with states and with Equipments, and check if there is still any link with that operator (he might be working for another company etc) and if not, then delete him from the operator database.

Absolutely not.

It's one thing to say "The operator who has id number 42 doesn't currently work for Vandelay, Inc." (You don't have a table for that kind of fact, but you should.) It's an entirely different thing to say "The operator who has id number 42 is no longer an operator."

In the first case, I might write a delete statement like this.

```
-- "The operator who has id number 42 
-- doesn't currently work for Vandelay, Inc."
delete from company_operators
where op_id = 42 and co_id = (select co_id 
                              from companies 
                              where co_name = 'Vandelay, Inc.')
```

Being a careful database designer, I'd have built the tables to cascade deletes. So the application programmers don't have to check anything else or delete anything else. Note that this wouldn't delete any facts about which equipment operator 42 can operate unless that fact was directly related to the fact that operator 42 currently works for Vandelay.

In the second case, I'd probably write a delete statement like this.

```
-- "The operator who has id number 42 is no longer an operator." 
delete from operators
where op_id = 42;
```

Again, cascading deletes takes care of the other tables. You don't have to check anything else or delete anything else.